# How to filter json output from file using python?

Tags: python, json

We'd like to filter the following json output from `testers.txt` for any `userid`'s in list form:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "user": {
        "user_id": "16214222",
        "username": "tester11"
    }
},
{
    "status": true,
    "user": {
        "user_id": "44223333",
        "username": "tester22"
    }
}
```

What we currently have (tried old code):

```
import json

with open('testers.txt') as fp:
     inText = fp.read()
data = json.loads(inText)
print data['user_id']
```

Finally the output should be:

```
16214222,
44223333
```

We currently get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.loads(inText)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 7 column 2 - line 14 column 2 (char 105 - 212)
```

*I'm new at stackoverflow - feel free to comment my question so I can improve myself.*

Comment: you sure about the input being a valid json?

Comment: No, what shall I change?

Comment: Next time when you are unsure about a json being a valid json, using this [website](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a leading and trailing square bracket on your `json` file, like so:

```
[{
    "status": true,
    "user": {
        "user_id": "16214222",
        "username": "tester11"
    }
},
{
    "status": true,
    "user": {
        "user_id": "44223333",
        "username": "tester22"
    }
}]
```

And then you can do the following:

```
import json

with open('testers.txt') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

for user in data:
    print user['user']['user_id']
```

returning:

```
16214222
44223333
```

Answer (score 0):

You will know the json is an invalid one upon using [this website](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate the json.

You need to add a [] to make the json in a list of jsons as you json is not a valid one.

```
inText = '''
[{
    "status": true,
    "user": {
        "user_id": "16214222",
        "username": "tester11"
    }
},
{
    "status": true,
    "user": {
        "user_id": "44223333",
        "username": "tester22"
    }
}]
'''

import json

with open('testers.txt') as fp:
    inText = fp.read()
data = json.loads(inText)
print [d['user']['user_id'] for d in data]
```

Output:

```
[u'16214222', u'44223333']
```

Answer (score -1):

use jq can achieve what you want easily.

```
# jq '.[] | .user | .user_id' testers.txt

"16214222"
"44223333"
```

assume you json in below format:

```
[{
    "status": true,
    "user": {
        "user_id": "16214222",
        "username": "tester11"
    }
},
{
    "status": true,
    "user": {
        "user_id": "44223333",
        "username": "tester22"
    }
}]
```

Comment: The question asks how to do it using python and your answer uses `jq` instead.